# SQL: JOIN e Contar Numero Repetidos

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Tabelas do Banco]
Preciso fazer um JOIN da **Tabela Cliente** junto com a **Tabela Pedido**
e gostaria de comparar o **Cliente.id** o ID do cliente da tabela Cliente,
Junto com o que tem dentro da **tabela Pedido** no caso a **coluna Cliente_id** na tabela Pedido, e fazer uma contagem dentro da tabela Pedidos quantas vezes o ID do cliente se repete, por exemplo no caso da imagem teria que retornar 3, pois tem 741,741,741 três vezes o id do cliente dentro da tabela Pedido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas para isso não é necessário a junção, basta:

```
SELECT pedido.cliente_id, count(*) 
FROM pedido
HAVING (count(*) > 1)
GROUP BY pedido.cliente_id;
```